# Firefox open containing folder cannot find location

Tags: pantheon-files, firefox

I have Loki 0.4.1 installed with Firefox 60.0.1. I have some folder created in my download folder which have spaces in them, if I download to any of these folders and then try and select open container folder, or click to open the file directly, it replaces the location in Pantheon with a Zero where there was a space.

For an example I have a folder inside my Downloads folder called Linux Software, when selecting open containing folder inside firefox will try and navigate to Linux0Software

Up until this morning I was using a different OS yet with the same Firefox version, here there was no issue at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in elementary Juno.